# Serge Lang - Introduction to linear algebra, Linear Mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have these problems in Serge Lang's *Introduction to linear algebra*'s Linear Mappings section.

---

(a) What is the dimension of the subspace of $R_n$ consisting of those vectors $A = (a_1, ... ,a_n)$ such that $a_1 + ... + a_n = 0$?

I did the following.
A is a set of linearly dependent vectors. $a_1 + ... + a_{n-1} = -a_n$. So I think that the subspace can be generated by $(a_1, ... ,a_{n-1})$ Consequently the dimension of the subspace is $n - 1$.
Am I right?

---

(b) What is the dimension of the subspace of the space of $n$ x $n$ matrices $(a_{ij})$ such that
$a_{11} +···+a_{nn} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} = 0?$

The second one should somehow be similar to the first one. But I don't understand how to solve it. And also I don't see how can I make use of linear mappings in these problems.

---

The answers in the book's answer section are (a) $n - 1$ (b) $n^2 - 1$. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the vector $A\backslash a_n$? Is it $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-1})$? Or $(a_1,\dots, a_{n-1}, 0)$? Or something else? I would avoid using the notation $A\backslash a_n$ because it suggests that $A$ is a set and that $a_n$ is an element of that set, which is not true.

Comment: @SeraPhim Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part $(a)$

Think of the linear map

$T:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$T(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=a_1+a_2+..+a_n$

Notice that $T$ is non-zero linear transformation and the co-domain space is of dimension $1$

What is $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ ? What happens if we apply the Rank-Nullity Theorem ?

Similarly for $(b)$ ,take the mapping

$U:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$U(A) =\operatorname{tr}(A)$ .

Comment: The kernel is any multiply of $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$? I can't find the dimension of the kernel in order to use the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Comment: Have you noticed that the Kernel is the required subspace in the question whose dimension is to be found? Now , you find the dimension of $Ker (T)$ not directly but by using the Rank-Nullity Theorem and $Rank (T)=1$ .

Comment: Oh, sorry.. Yep, got it! It is n - 1, where n is the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ and 1 the dimension of Ker(T)